# Скрипт увеличения фото, помогите модифицировать

Tags: изображения, javascript

В JS вообще не шарю пока что, но с этим разобрался, а как можно модифицировать код, что бы при первом нажатии на миниатюру - появлялось большое изображение, а при повторном нажатии на мини - исчезало ? )

Вот код:

```
 function show(img) {
      var fullsize = document.getElementById("fullsize");
      fullsize.style.display = "block";
      fullsize.innerHTML = "<img class='bigimg' src='" + img.src + "' alt='fullsize'  />";
  }

  function hide(img) {
      var fullsize = document.getElementById("fullsize");
      fullsize.style.display = "none";
      fullsize.innerHTML = "";
  }
```

А вызывается вот так:

```
<img class="miniimg" id="image" onClick="show(this);" onMouseDown="hide(this);" src="/img/1/2.png">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<img class="miniimg" id="image" onClick="toggle(this);" src="/img/1/2.png">

function show(img) {
  var fullsize = document.getElementById("fullsize");
  fullsize.style.display = "block";
  fullsize.innerHTML = "<img class='bigimg' src='" + img.src + "' alt='fullsize'/>";}

function hide(img) {
  var fullsize = document.getElementById("fullsize");
  fullsize.style.display = "none";
  fullsize.innerHTML = "";
}
var state = 0;
function toggle(img){
    if(state === 0)
    {
        show(img);
    }
    else
    {
        hide(img);
    }
}
```

Comment: Проблема появляется в другом - при нажатии на мини изображение - открывается большое, но при нажатии на другое мини изображение - предыдущее сворачивается,и нужно второй раз кликать по изображению, что бы открыть его (

Comment: Тогда добавьте hide(); перед var fullsize = ... в тело function show(){}

Comment: Благодарю, я сделал немного по-другому )) Но Вы мне подали эту идею, а сделал я вот так:

     function show(img) {
      hide(img);
      var fullsize = document.getElementById("fullsize");
      fullsize.style.display = "block";
      fullsize.innerHTML = "<img class='bigimg' onClick=\"hide(this);\" src='" + img.src + "'/>";
    }